# Eloquent ORM - how to use WHERE to get object?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to select an object from my table using `where`, like this:

```
$obj = Product::where('column_name', '=', 'string')->get();
```

But $obj is in json.

How can I get a normal object?

Comment: If you `var_dump($obj)` what do you get? Normally you should get Eloquent Collection object. The Json string representation you get if you call `toJson()` method on the collection or if you return it straight from the route.

Answer (score 4):

```
$product = Product::where('model','like', '%table%')
    ->orderBy('price', 'desc')
    ->get();


var_dump($product);
```

Will give you Eloquent Colection of objects and it isn't jSON

```
var_dump($product->toJson());
```

Will give you JSON Object

But you should also consider basic query.

```
$product = DB::table('product')->select('id', 'model')
    ->where('product_id' ,  '=' ,  $id)
    ->get();
```

For collection of all objects use:

```
$products = Product::all();
```

etc

```
$product = Product::find($id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `first()` method to get the object (assuming you only need to process one result).

Using `get()` method will return an array because the query builder doesn't know if you only have one result or more.

hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you return an Eloquent object to the client then it will be represented as JSON (perfect for APIs). `var_dump()` the object to see that it is, in fact, an Eloquent object.